# Ansible - template file from variable and include only content of that variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

For lack of a better title, I have this dummy variable, this task and this j2 template:

```yaml
# variable
my_list:
  - filename: something.conf
    content: hello
  - filename: else.conf
    content: asdf
```

```yaml
# conf.j2
{% for item in my_list %}
{{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

```yaml
# task
- name: set config
  template:
    src: conf.j2
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item.filename }}"
  loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

This results in having 2 files on /tmp, `something.conf` and `else.conf`, having the same content.

**Q**: How can I configure Ansible so that per filename, it only 'pastes/templates' the content for that filename. Note that the items in `my_list` will grow.

Expected output on target vm:

```bash
# cat /tmp/something.conf
hello
# cat /tmp/else.conf
asdf
```

Do I have to create an `if` clause in the template, or edit the loop in a certain way?

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop `{% for ...`  in the template?

Comment: I thought that was gonna make me closer to a solution, build it from there. But now that you say it, it might not even be remotely close to the solution.

Comment: Indeed, the solution is removing the loop from the template.

Comment: I’m slammed. Talking about overthinking. Thanks!